# React Native Redux: props not updating after API call

Tags: android, react-native, react-redux

I am quite new to React / React Native / Redux so I feel I am doing something wrong.

**The problem**

I want to show a spinner while an API is called, and an error message once this API call fails. Props are not updating, and so the components don't show the desired message or spinner

**The code (only the relevant chunks)**

*The component*

```
class Home extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.tokenGet();
    }

    renderSpinner() {
        if (this.props.loading) {
            return (
                <Spinner size="large" />
            );
        }
        return null;
    }

    renderMessage() {
        if (this.props.message) {
            return (
                <Text style={{flex: 1, background: red, color: black}}>
                    { this.props.message }
                </Text>
            )
         }
         return null;
    }

    render() {
        return (
             { this.renderSpinner() }
             { this.renderMessage() }
        )
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const { auth } = state;
    const {
        loading,
        token,
        message
    } = auth || {
        loading: false,
        token: null,
        message: null
    };
    return {
        loading,
        token,
        message
    }
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps, { tokenGet } )(Home);
```

*The action creator*

```
export const tokenGet = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'TOKEN_GET_START'});

        // Perform the actual API call
        let requestToken = fetch(apiBaseUrl + "/tokens", {
             method: "POST",
             headers: {
                  'Accept': 'application/json',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
             },
             body: JSON.stringify(.....)
        });
        Promise
             .race([timeout, requestToken])
             .then((response) => response.json())
             .then((responseJson) => {
                   ... not relevant ...
             })
             .catch((error) => {
                 dispatch({ type: 'TOKEN_GET_FAIL', payload: error});
             });
```

*The timeout function, which gets called when the server fails to respond*

```
let timeout = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(reject, 2000, 'Request timed out. Please check your internet connection.');
});
```

*The reducer*

```
import {
    TOKEN_GET_START,
    TOKEN_GET_SUCCESS,
    TOKEN_GET_FAIL
} from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    loading: false,
    token: null,
    message: null
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case TOKEN_GET_START:
            return { ...state, loading: true };
        case TOKEN_GET_SUCCESS:
            return { ...state, loading: false, token: action.payload };
        case TOKEN_GET_FAIL:
            return { ...state, loading: false, message: action.payload };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

*The combined reducers*

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import AuthReducer from './AuthReducer';

export default combineReducers({
    auth: AuthReducer
});
```

The actual behavior is that the props don't change and no message or spinner is visible. With some console logs I know that the API call ends because of the timeout. I am not sure if the state gets updated properly though. I don't know in at which point I can console log this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be because of the quotes in `'TOKEN_GET_FAIL'`

That is a string and not the `const` I need. So I changed to `TOKEN_GET_FAIL` and it works.